# Xamarin forms: Listview: Itemtemplate: Datatemplate: I dont have TextCell in xaml

Tags: c#, android, wpf, xaml

I have a problem. In Datatemplate i cant reach TextCell in xaml. Anybody can help me?

[image: Problem]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Spirocco.MedicationPage"
         Title="Gyógyszerek">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ListView>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Update: I reach it but the VS dont show it. 
In first answer there is a solution.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? In its current state it's unclear what you're asking, and most importantly - what you're *actually* trying to achieve. Please update your question to clarify what you intend to solve.

Comment: My short experience with Xamarin showed me that intellisense is a hit or miss on many occasion, a quick search on SO will show you the same. Many says that disabling Resharper might work, I'm not using Resharper and had intellisense issue, so not sure. If you add a `TextCell` to your `DataTemplate`, does it work?

Comment: I wanted this. This is working now. 
<ListView x:Name="Medications" ItemsSource="{Binding Medications}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ImageCell ImageSource="{Binding Icon}" Text="{Binding Name}" Detail="{Binding Type}" Tapped="ImageCell_Tapped"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

Comment: @TamásDeák - please avoid posting your answer in the comments. I would suggest posting your solution as an answer, if this is what you used, and you feel that it may be useful to future visitors to this question. But, I would still update your question so that it is clearer what exactly you were/are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<StackLayout>
    <ListView x:Name="Medications" ItemsSource="{Binding Medications}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ImageCell ImageSource="{Binding Icon}" Text="{Binding Name}" Detail="{Binding Type}" Tapped="ImageCell_Tapped"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```